# Cannot find symbol after gradle modification. (PushPlugin and FCMService)

Tags: android, maven, gradle, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using ionic and i'm having some trouble building my Android App.
I was getting this error:
**Could not find com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2.**
And it was fixed when i included the maven section on my gradle file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z2Xe.png)

After that i'm getting another error when i try to build my android app.
It is not finding some simbles related to the FCMService and to the PushPlugin on the package android.app. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juL5f.png)

Comment: Solved changing the phonegap-plugin-push version to 1.10.5